# how to parse json in basic4android?

Tags: android, json, basic4android

I want to parse JSON from URL to android label in basic4android .

I try this but not working :

```
Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
Dim Label1 As Label
Dim job As HttpJob

job.Initialize("Job", Me)
job.Download("http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/82")


If job.Success = True Then

Dim parser As JSONParser
parser.Initialize(job.GetString)
Dim root As Map = parser.NextObject

Dim name As String = root.Get("name")
Label1.Text = Title
End if
```

Comment: Instead of "not working" you should tell what is the problem. First guess is that you should use `name` not `Title`

Answer (score 0):

You have `Label1.Text = Title` where it should be `Label1.Text = name`